# Finding all unitary representations of the connected Poincaré group

Tags: lie-groups, unitary-representations

I am studying representation theory of Lie groups and its combination to theoretical physics, and I am concerned about the following. Is there an exhaustive way to find all unitary representations of the connected Poincaré Group $SO(1,3)_e\ltimes\mathbb{R}^4$. I am thinking that Mackey Theory that do the trick, but is anyone familiar with other options?

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical question that was solved by Wigner in ["On unitary representations of the inhomogeneous Lorentz group"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968551?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). There is a nice (modern and elementary) exposition in Sternberg's book *Group Theory and Physics*. [This page](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/Projects/Poincare/) (from a common contributor here) looks to have a lot of the references.